# Lagrange Interpolation in java using BigInteger

Tags: java, interpolation, biginteger

I am trying to find a function to perform Lagrange Interpolation in java.  I have 3 (x,y) pairs, where x and y are BigInteger objects, and would like to use some interpolation function to determine f(0) for the polynomial f used to calculate my x,y these pairs.  Something like this seems perfect, except that this class doesn't seem to actually belong to a package I can import: http://nssl.eew.technion.ac.il/files/Projects/thresholddsaimporvement/doc/javadoc/Lagrange.html

Forgive me if my question is naive, any help I can get would really be appreciated.

Comment: And what is problem? Maybe you should write custom function to interpolate using class Lagrange?

Answer (score 0):

A similar class seems to be in [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/math/). This is probably going to be much more reliable than what you found.

http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/analysis/polynomials/PolynomialFunctionLagrangeForm.html

It would appear that you construct it with `PolynomialFunctionLagrangeForm(double[] x, double[] y)`, then call `value(0)` to get the value at `x = 0`.

Comment: Thank you, I had actually just stumbled across this.  My issue is that my y values could potentially be very large, so I was hoping to find something that could accommodate things of type BigInteger or BigDecimal.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Didn't see the part about BigIntegers. Well, it is open source, and the operation it's performing isn't horribly complicated, so it may be worth just replacing those `double`s with `BigDecimal`s for your own use.